# How do I add multiple versions of a list (meaning I'm updating the list) to a list, without having all the lists within the list be exactly the same?

Tags: python, list

I'm having trouble getting the output I want. I want to create a list and have the first element of a new list be that initial list. Then I want to modify the first list, and have the new modified version of that list be the second element of the new list. Right now, this outputs [[2,3,4,5,5],[2,3,4,5,5]]. How would I modify it so that the output is [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,5]]?

```
noChange = [1,2,3,4,5]
lotsOfLists = []

lotsOfLists += [noChange]

for i in range(4):
    noChange[i] += 1
lotsOfLists += [noChange] 

print(lotsOfLists) # current output: [[2, 3, 4, 5, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 5]]
# WANT: [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,5]]
```

Comment: That subject line is a tongue twister

Comment: `listOfLists` contains many references to the same list (i.e. `noChange`). You have to make new list instances if you want them to be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are accessed by reference, so you need `.copy()` to create a new one.

```
noChange = [1,2,3,4,5]
lotsOfLists = []

lotsOfLists += [noChange.copy()]

for i in range(4):
    noChange[i] += 1
lotsOfLists += [noChange]

print(lotsOfLists) # output: [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,5]]
```

As others say, you can also use the slicing operator `[:]` to achieve the same result. IMHO, the semantics is different. With the slicing operator, you tell a reader that you want to slice something. With the copy() operation, you tell a reader, that you want to copy something.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use the line

```
lotsOfLists += [noChange]
```

change it to

```
lotsOfLists += [noChange[:]]
```

Adding the `[:]` will make a copy of the list and not change it later

Answer (score 0):

Lists are mutable, that is causing the trouble. Use slices for copies.

```
noChange = [1,2,3,4,5]
lotsOfLists = []

lotsOfLists += [noChange[:]]

for i in range(4):
    noChange[i] += 1
lotsOfLists += [noChange[:]] 

print(lotsOfLists) #output [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 5]]
```